# htaccess, IF and FilesMatch

Tags: .htaccess

Why does not work? Gives the server 500 error If you remove the IF - it all works.

```
<If "%{HTTP_HOST} == 'site.ru'">
   <FilesMatch "\.php$">
      AddHandler x-httpd-php6 .php
   </FilesMatch>
</If>
```

Comment: What version of apache httpd are you using?

Comment: Does the error log give any indications about what the server may not like?

Comment: @MrTux Forgot. I have Apache 2.0. In this version there is no support.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [<if](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#if)-environment was introduced in Apache 2.4 (http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/new_features_2_4.html), you're using Apache 2.0 so it's not supported and cannot work.